# Electron JS - blocked on package build

Tags: electron, electron-forge, npm-run

I'm currently trying to make a Electron-JS application and have started a projet using `npx create-electron-app myApp`. I've managed to develop what I want, and have ran it many times using `npm start` and it worked pretty well.

Now I'm trying to build the application using `npm run make` (which calls `electron-forge make`). The problem is that this command get stuck on :
Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64

I've been waiting for an hour and I don't know what I could try to solve this problem. Anyone got an idea ?

If needed, here's my system informations (using `neofetch` command) :

```
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            boux@GB-ElemOS 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         -------------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: UX31A 1.0 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 4.15.0-135-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 4 hour, 9 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 3171 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Theme: Elementary [GTK3] 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    Icons: Elementary [GTK3] 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     Terminal: io.elementary.t 
    eeeee                 eeeee       CPU: Intel i7-3517U (4) @ 3.000GHz 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            Memory: 1934MiB / 3831MiB
```

Edit : It doesn't work for me on a new project, without any changes. If I run

```
npx create-electron-app foo
cd foo/
npm start
```

The application starts correctly. But if I then try

```
npm run make
```

the output is

```
> foo@1.0.0 make /home/boux/Projets/Electron/foo
> electron-forge make

✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config
We need to package your application before we can make it
⠇ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
```

and it prepares the package...forever...

Answer (score 0):

don`t use electron-forge make, I think you could use electron-packager or electron-builder to pack it. I have the problem like you, and solved it packing by electron-builder.